# Add UITableViewController to Current View Programmatically

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

I need to display UITableViewController programmatically from existing view.

I have a MyAppViewController and the button on its view should open a new UITableViewController. But I cannot seem to get it working so far. Here is how UITableViewController looks like:

```
@interface SecondViewController : UITableViewController{}
```

and on the main view I add table view controller using the following:

```
SecondViewController vc2 = [[SecondViewController alloc] init];
vc2.view.frame = {...}
[self.view addSubview: vc2.view];
```

This is how I would normally add a simple view controller so I thought UITableViewController is the same.

The result I get is empty cells on the entire screen. This is because of the delegate not set, I assume, but where would I set it? So my confusion is the delegate setters on UITableViewController view controller and displaying UITableViewController correctly from the main view controller's view.

Comment: A bit confused, you are asking how to add a `UITableViewController` or how to set the cell's content for the `UITableView`?

Comment: how to add a UITableViewController... if I do it successfully I think I will be able to take care of cell content

Comment: @Vad: are you using storyboards?

Comment: No, I'd like to make it happen programmatically if possible

Comment: @Vad: you can still do it programmatically even it if it in a storyboard.  I ask because the syntax will be a little different if they are views on a storyboard vs if you have .nib vs if the controller is set up completely programmatically.

Comment: @Vad: also, just to be clear, you want to remove your MyAppViewController from the screen and replace it with SecondViewController correct?

Comment: @GeneralMike: Yes. Adding as a subview is OK too.

Comment: @Steven Yeah You are Right he just creating the Confusion...!!!But No Problem that's The Thing how we leanrn.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## EDIT

This answer is outdated. The correct way to add a view controller's view as a subview of another view controller is to implement a container view controller.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers.html

## ORIGINAL ANSWER

Your pattern is a bit out of the ordinary. The most common way to do what you are describing is to initialize and present SecondViewController. If that's in fact what you want I highly recommend you peruse Apple's docs on how to create, customize, and present `UIViewController` and `UITableViewController`.

If you know all of that and really want to do something custom then read on.

Instead you are creating an instance of SecondViewController and rather than presenting it, you are adding it's view to the current view controllers view. If you know what you're trying to accomplish and this is in fact your desired result then go for it.

There is more than one way to configure this general pattern. I'll stick to the simplest way in this example.

1) `MainViewController` (MVC) should retain the `SecondViewController` (SVC) instance in a property as long as it is needed.

2) SVC is a subclass of `UITableViewController` so by default, it is set as the `dataSource` and `delegate` for it's `UITableView`. That means you need to implement the `UITableViewDataSource` and `UITableViewDelegate` methods in `SVC` for your table to be populated with data. Assuming `MVC` knows what data needs to go into the table, it should pass this to `SVC`. The simplest way is to define a property on `SVC` that can be set in `MVC` at initialization time.

3) Assuming there is a way to dismiss the table after it has been presented, you'll want `MVC` to do that. Basically, `MVC` would remove `SVC`'s view from it's superview and then set the `SVC` property to nil.

Here's some quick psuedo-code. I wrote the bare minimum as an example.

```
// MainViewController.h
//
#import "SecondViewController.h"

@interface MainViewController : UIViewController
@property (nonatomic, strong) SecondViewController *svc;
@end

// MainViewController.m
//
#import "MainViewController.h"

@implementation MainViewController

// init and configure views w/ init, loadView, viewDidLoad, etc

// present SecondViewController
- (void)presentSecondViewController:(id)sender {
    self.svc = [[SecondViewController alloc] init];
    // this example uses an array as the SVC data
    self.svc.tableData = @[@"first", @"second", @"third", @"fourth"];
    self.svc.view.frame = self.view.bounds;
    [self.view addSubview:self.svc.view];
}

// dismiss SecondViewController
- (void)dismissSecondViewController:(id)sender {
    if (self.svc) {
        [self.svc.view removeFromSuperview];
        self.svc = nil;
    }
}

// SecondViewController.h
//
@interface SecondViewController : UITableViewController
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *tableData;
@end

// SecondViewController.m
//
@implementation SecondViewController

// init and configure views w/ init, loadView, viewDidLoad, etc

// override tableData getter to create empty array if nil
- (NSArray *)tableData
{
    if (!tableData) {
        _tableData = @[];
    }
    return _tableData;
}

// override tableData setter to reload tableView
- (void)setTableData:(NSArray *)tableData
{
    _tableData = tableData;
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}

// implement UITableViewDelegate and UITableViewDataSource methods using
// the self.tableData array
```

Comment: You are right. I did not need @interface SecondViewController : UIViewController<UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource> as many stated.

Answer (score 0):

Here is The Code

1)Add DataSource and Delegate `.h`

2)Create SOme Code in `.m`

```
   thisTableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(6.5, 60,      self.view.bounds.size.width - 10, 350) style:UITableViewStylePlain];

    [thisTableView setBounces:NO];
    thisTableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

thisTableView.delegate = self;
thisTableView.dataSource = self;
[self.view addSubview:thisTableView];
    [thisTableView release];
```

Comment: how does this tableview knows it belongs to SecondViewController?

Comment: @Vad Actually you should be clear on your requirement as you said you need to create the `TableView` on button click .so here what you can do is that as i mentioned how to create tableView in SecondViewController and on button click navigate to that secondViewController or present That View Modally .Hence You need to place that code in `Second ViewController` and one thing you have to write some code inside these methods for working properly.

Comment: Sorry for confusion but my SecondViewController is already a UITableViewController. For some reasons I prefer to keep it that way. Based on this, is your first code valid: **UIViewController** or am I supposed to keep it as UITableViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>

Comment: @Vad As far I know if you create your Your SecondViewController Inherited From UIViewController.You can give More Flexibility to your code

Answer (score 0):

In your header you'll have to tell your view controller to conform to UITableViewDataSource and UITableViewDelegate. Add this right after "UIViewController"

```
<UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>
```

Then in your implementation file you'll need to add the delegate and data source methods for the table like:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

And

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

You can find a full list in the [UITableViewDataSource](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UITableViewDataSource) and [UITableViewDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UITableViewDelegate) class references.

Additionally, where you alloc init your table view you'll need to set it's delegate and datasource to the current class:

```
[myTableView setDelegate:self];
[myTableView setDataSource:self];
```

Comment: Do I need <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate> considering my SecondViewController is already a UITableViewController?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, first off I think what you are doing with `[self.view addSubview]` is piling all the views in your project into the same view controller, where the more traditional way to do it is to dismiss a view controller when you are done with it and create the new view controller on it's own. The piling up you are doing is unconventional, and I think it will be misleading to whoever tries to look at your code in the future.  Additionally, it's going to be a headache if you actually start trying to do standard navigation.  Also, it looks like a memory management nightmare (although I admit I'm still a little fuzzy on that, so I don't know if ARC would clean it up for you or not, if you are actually using ARC).  That said, there are cases where you might be trying to do that - but if you're not sure, that means it isn't what you want to be doing (if it is what you want to do, check out XJones' answer).  What I think you're looking for is `presentViewController` - that is the more conventional way to get rid of an unneeded controller and replace it with a new one.  Get rid of

```
vc2.view.frame = {...}
[self.view addSubview: vc2.view];
```

and replace it with

```
[self presentViewController:vc2 animated:/*YES or NO, try them both and use whichever one you like better*/ completion:NULL];
```

NOTE: I'm not entirely sure what `completion` does (I think it maybe allows you to run an extra method once vc2 is built - there are some examples if you google "presentViewController examples" that you could take a look at to get more information, or check the [Apple Docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html)).  I do know that keeping it `NULL` will work, and probably do what you need.

Once you do all this, you will be right back to where you are now, where you will have a view with a bunch of empty cells on it (but you will have gotten there in a more conventional way).

From here, you need to add some code to your SecondViewController.m to tell it what you want to show.  Generally, you'll have an array of strings and you want the 1st cell of your table to have a label that displays 1st string in that array, 2nd cell shows 2nd string, and so on.  To do this, you'll have something like `cell.textLabel = [myArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];`.

There is a lot more to setting up a UITableViewController than I could get into in this post, so check out some tutorials on YouTube or something, as they have already taken the time to explain everything you need in a much more digestible format (I found [this one](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9S114beUwPM) to be very helpful when I was first starting using table views, but there are tons of others there too).